# "Buchungsangebot mit Option"

Tags: german-to-english

Was bedeutet "mit Option" in "Buchungsangebot mit Option bis xx/xx/xxxx" ?

Denn wenn ich das lese, muss ich mich fragen: "Mit welcher Option?"

Comment: Um diese Frage beantworten zu können, müsste man Englisch können. Du bist hier aber in einem Deutsch-Forum. Fragen, deren Beantwortung Kenntnisse in anderen Sprachen als Deutsch erfordern, sind hier leider off-topic.

Comment: Tut mir Leid. Ich dachte ich hätte die Frage im German to English Forum geschrieben.

Answer (score 1):

Das bedeutet, das die Buchung des Objektes, z.B. eines Hotelzimmers, bis zu dem angegebenen Datum erfolgen muss. Bis dahin hat man quasi ein Recht auf das Objekt. Danach wird es auch anderen Personen wieder angeboten.

Quelle: http://www.gastrowissen.de/wissen/berichtsheft/angebotsschreiben.htm